# App crashes on Button Click. Trying to dynamically create edit texts

Tags: android, button, android-edittext, logcat

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.new_class_container);

    mLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.overall_layout);
    mEditLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.edittext_layout);

    assignName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.assign_edit);
    assignWeight = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.weight_edit);

    addMore = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_add);
    addMore.setOnClickListener(onClick());
}

private OnClickListener onClick() {
    return new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            //mLinearLayout.addView(mEditLinearLayout);
        }
    };
}
```

XML FILE:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/overall_layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient_gray"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<!-- Inserts Subject Name to Save -->

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/class_textview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/write_class_name"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#4169E1" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/class_edit"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/example_name"
        android:inputType="textCapWords"
        android:singleLine="true" />
</LinearLayout>

<!-- Assignment Name and Weight -->

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/assign_textview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/write_assignment_type"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#4169E1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/weight_textview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/write_assign_percent"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#4169E1" />
</LinearLayout>

<!-- Enter information for Assignment Name and Weight -->

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/edittext_layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/assign_edit"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:hint="@string/example_assign"
        android:inputType="textCapWords"
        android:singleLine="true" >
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/weight_edit"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:hint="@string/example_weight"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:maxLength="2"
        android:singleLine="true" >
    </EditText>
</LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_add"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:text="@string/more_assign" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I have the overall LinearLayout in which I have multiple layouts and I want to on the click of a button dynamically create edit texts but I am having trouble with that part and the application keeps crashing. I'm not sure what I should do to fix this issue. If I go to the log cat

```
!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 4 0 2014-02-15 17:40:25.957
!MESSAGE 
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.getDefaultProperties(RenderSessionImpl.java:1476)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.BridgeRenderSession.getDefaultProperties(BridgeRenderSession.java:68)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.ViewHierarchy.getDefaultProperties(ViewHierarchy.java:710)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.properties.XmlProperty.getStringValue(XmlProperty.java:209)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.properties.XmlProperty.getValue(XmlProperty.java:221)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.properties.XmlPropertyEditor.getText(XmlPropertyEditor.java:116)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.properties.XmlPropertyEditor.paint(XmlPropertyEditor.java:131)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.model.property.table.PropertyTable.drawProperty(PropertyTable.java:1309)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.model.property.table.PropertyTable.drawContent(PropertyTable.java:1151)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.model.property.table.PropertyTable.handlePaint(PropertyTable.java:1094)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.model.property.table.PropertyTable.access$200(PropertyTable.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.model.property.table.PropertyTable$3.handleEvent(PropertyTable.java:187)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4136)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1458)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1481)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1466)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.drawWidget(Control.java:1244)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.drawWidget(Canvas.java:167)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.drawRect(Widget.java:741)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.drawRect(Canvas.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5473)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSendSuper(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.applicationNextEventMatchingMask(Display.java:4875)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.applicationProc(Display.java:5241)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSend(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.NSApplication.nextEventMatchingMask(NSApplication.java:94)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3615)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1053)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:942)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:588)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:543)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
```

Answer (score 0):

The code below shows how to add a LinearLayout dynamically to your "master" linear layout.
    LinearLayout Master;

```
LayoutInflater inflater;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Master = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.container);
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                inflater.inflate(R.layout.row,  Master);
            }
        });

    }
```

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Add" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button1" >
    </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

<!--row.xml-->

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="239dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

If you just want to add a single EditText, you can skip using the inflater and do:

```
EditText txt = new EditText(this, null);
Master.addView(txt);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do this in somewhat different approach!, first i would get the create the `edit text`in the xml,then get into the onCreate method ,but would set the visiblity to GONE,using `variableOfEditText.setVisibility(View.GONE)` and when the user clicks the button ,in the onclick method ,i would make it visible`variableOfEditText.setVisiblity(View.VISIBLE)`.Make sure you declare the edittext variable as a class variable
Another suggestion i would like to give is ,use onClick for a button ,instead of using anonymous inner classes ,it's clean

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the logcat you pasted here is not complete, because it doesn't mention your code anywhere. When the crash happens, look for the line "Caused by:" in logcat and below you will probably find references to your own application package. It would be very helpful to see where this null pointer happens in your activity, because it's not obvious from the code you pasted into your question.

1.) The line you have commented out, //mLinearLayout.addView(mEditLinearLayout);, would not work, it would cause an IllegalStateException, as the mEditLinearLayout is already part of mLinearLayout, so you can't add it again. But you seem to be getting an NPE instead.

If you simply want the EditTexts you defined in your XML to not be visible when you start the activity, but have them appear on click, just make the edittext_layout "gone" in the XML like this:

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/edittext_layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:visibility="gone">
```

And then in your onClick method, make the layout appear, like this:

```
    public void onClick(View v) {
        mEditLinearLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
```

2.) If you really want to create a new EditText every time the user clicks the "add" button, then you probably don't need any EditTexts inside your edittext_layout to begin with. Just inflate a new EditText onClick, add it to your mEditLinearLayout and keep a reference to it in a List field in your activity later.

Define a simple EditText in a separate XML file, called edit_text.xml, like this:

```
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
```

And then:

```
    private ArrayList<EditText> mEditTextList;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.new_class_container);
        mEditTextList = new ArrayList<EditText>();

        mLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.overall_layout);
        mEditLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.edittext_layout);

        assignName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.assign_edit);
        assignWeight = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.weight_edit);

        addMore = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_add);
        addMore.setOnClickListener(onClick());
    }

    private OnClickListener onClick() {
        return new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                EditText editText = (EditText) YourActivity.this.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.edit_text, null);
                mEditTextList.add(editText);
                mEditLinearLayout.addView(editText);
            }
        };
    }
```

Just don't forget in onDestroy, to clear the list:

```
    @Override
        protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mEditTextList.clear();
        mEditTextList = null;
    }
```

Comment: I have two edittexts that I want to create every time I click the add button though. Both these edittexts are beside one another. How would I take care of both them?

Comment: Ok, let's try to clarify what you really want. Do you want to have a maximum of 2 edittexts, or do you really want to add more and more (2 + 2 +2 ... and so on) every time this button is clicked?

If you want to have only one pair of edittexts, but so they are not visible until you click the button, then you will accomplish that if you follow solution 1 from my answer. Just define your layout in a way that they are positioned how you want them when they are visible.

If you want to have more than one pair of edittexts, then follow the instructions in solution 2 from my answer.